# Preprocessing: Is defining a shorthand for `import` legal?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c-preprocessor, c++20

For solving a code-golf challenge, I want to produce the smallest possible code. I had the idea of defining a shorthand for `import`:

```
#define I import
I<vector>;
```

[short godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/3qrWGoz6e)

Of course, the intention here is to reuse `I` to actually save bytes.

Is this legal in C++20?

Thoughts / What I found out so far:

- According to cppreference, ["The module and import directives are also preprocessing directives"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor). So I think it would boil down to the question whether we have a guarantee that the preprocessor first has to replace I with our definition?
- I think handling the `import` directive should happen in translation phase 4, and for the whole phase, `I` should not be macro-expanded unless specified otherwise ([[cpp.pre]-7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/cpp#pre-7)). Is it specified otherwise for this case?
- Is it possible this works as part of the [preprocessor rescan](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/cpp.rescan)?
- Clang and GCC on godbolt do not compile, but AFAIK they don't yet support importing standard library headers without extra steps, and they give the same error message with the shorthand version, which indicates it would work(?)
- The same approach, but with `include` instead of `import`, does not work with gcc and clang and thus probably isn't legal.

Comment: Why are you considering legality in a code-golf challenge?

Comment: I think you'd be hard-pressed to find a code-golf site that already uses C++20 anyway.

Comment: It's not for a code-golf stackexchange question, but for an external challenge, with custom rules. One of the rules is that we can pick the c++ standard version we want, thus we can choose c++20 if we wish. However, our program has to be legal in the chosen standard and must not rely on implementation-specific behavior.

Comment: I think [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/cpp.import#1) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Won't work anyway, the pre-processor does nothing than transform text, it is not able to create new pre-processor directives, which is what you'd be trying.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for the link. I may misunderstand, but I think this rules out the inverse situation though, i.e. it says `#define import X` followed by `import <vector>;` would be illegal.

Comment: @Aconcagua: For me, it looks like what I posted would work with GCC and clang on godbolt -- with the `#define I import` used, they give the same error as if just using `import <vector>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

[[cpp.pre]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/cpp.pre#1):

> A *preprocessing directive* consists of a sequence of preprocessing
> tokens that satisfies the following constraints: At the start of
> translation phase 4, the first token in the sequence, referred to as a
> *directive-introducing token*, begins with the first character in the
> source file (optionally after whitespace containing no new-line
> characters) or follows whitespace containing at least one new-line
> character, and is [...]

Preprocessing-directive-ness is determined at the start of translation phase 4, prior to any macro replacement. Therefore, `I<vector>;` is not recognized as a directive, and the `import` from the macro expansion of `I` is not [replaced by the *import-keyword* token](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/cpp.import#4). This in turn means that it is not recognized as a [*module-import-declaration*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/module.import#nt:module-import-declaration) during translation phase 7, and is instead simply an ill-formed attempt to use the identifier `import` without a preceding declaration.

The point of this dance is to ensure that build systems can know a file's dependencies without having to fully preprocess the file - which would be required if imports can be formed from macro replacement.